# After uninstalling Visual Studio 2012, cannot open Azure cloud projects in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, visual-studio-2012

Getting a message box saying `The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\1.4\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  C:\MyProject\MyProject.ccproj` when trying to load a cloud project. This is after uninstalling Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2012 uninstaller left behind a settings file in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\4.0\ that just needs to be deleted.